# ipython profiler

Tags: ipython

I have some code in python that works but is unfortunately super slow. Someone at #python suggested that I can run the code through a profiler to see the lines and functions in which the code was taking the most amount of time.

The python source code that I want to profile reads from STDIN. But since the input is large I compiled the input as a file so that I can simply redirect it to the python code at the shell. So at the shell, I issue the command..

```
cat input | python pythonsource.py
```

The problem is, when I try to run the profiler in ipython I can't seem to find a way to redirect the input to the python code. At the ipython shell, I tried,

```
run -p -l 1.0 pythonsource.py input (didn't work. simply waits at STDIN for input)
run -p -l 1.0 pythonsource.py << input (didn't work)
run -p -l 1.0 cat input | python pythonsource.py (didn't work.)
```

I'm not sure how to do I can make the ipython profiler command redirect the input to STDIN for the pythonsource to read from. Could someone please tell me how to fix this? Or have I got it totally wrong? Maybe there is some other cleaner, more smarter way of profiling python code?

And maybe what I ask next should be a part of another question..but I was wondering what does ipython mean when it refers to "primitive calls" in some of the output of the ipython profiler?

Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know, piping in stdin is incompatible with IPython's `%run`. You'll have to run profiling manually: http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html#instant-user-s-manual

Answer (score 0):

The right way to redirect input on *the shell commandline* is as follows:

```
cat input | run -p -l 1.0 python pythonsource.py

run -p -l 1.0 python pythonsource.py < input
```

The syntax `<< string` creates a "here document", it does not redirect input.

From the python prompt (and hopefully in ipython), you can redirect standard input like this:

```
import sys
save_stdin = sys.stdin
sys.stdin = open('input')
run -p <etc.>
sys.stdin = save_stdin # Restore the real stdin
```

Or (recommended) you could rewrite your source to work with a filename: If you call it as follows, "input" will be in `sys.argv[1]` and you can open it and read from it:

```
python pythonsource.py input
```

Comment: I tried both of those commands on the ipython shell.. and neither of them worked. For the first command I get `sh: run: not found`
`cat: write error: Broken pipe` and the second simply waits at the ipython prompt for more input from STDIN. I could try the third option but I wanted to know if it was possible to do run the profiler on the python code and its input file without modifying the code.

Comment: Sorry, I was careless. Your attempts wouldn't have worked on the shell commandline, so I just gave the correct usage.

Comment: Thank you, but I used the -cProfile method that was mentioned in the link suggested by Thomas K. It seems much easier and it works right on the command line without any modification to source..